# Unnest and split function returning error in pyspark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a query that works great in Presto format (when executing in Athena). However when I run the same query in AWS Glue (via a Python Spark.SQL dataframe), I get an error saying "AnalysisException: Column 'metric_value' does not exist. Did you mean one of the following? []; line 10 pos 30" (it definitely exists). This error is only present when the cross join line in the code below is there. If I take this line out (which works fine in athena/presto), the glue job runs fine as well.

An example of the value in the metric_value column would be {14311, 242342134, 13132}

Below is the query:

```
df1 = spark.sql("""
select * FROM database.table
WHERE date(load_date) = current_date - interval '1' day
    """)

df1.createOrReplaceTempView("table1")
    
df2 = spark.sql("""  
SELECT load_date, load_hr, timestamp,
ne_name, object, metric_value, 
MIN(CAST((CASE WHEN trim(split_part) = '' THEN NULL ELSE trim(split_part) END) AS DOUBLE))/100 AS MIN_UTIL, 
MAX(CAST((CASE WHEN trim(split_part) = '' THEN NULL ELSE trim(split_part) END) AS DOUBLE))/100 AS 
MAX_UTIL, AVG(CAST((CASE WHEN trim(split_part) = '' THEN NULL ELSE trim(split_part) 
END) AS DOUBLE))/100 AS AVG_UTIL
FROM table1
cross join UNNEST(CAST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(metric_value, '[{}]',''), ',') AS ARRAY<VARCHAR(132)>)) AS t(split_part)
WHERE metric_name = 'util'
group by load_date, load_hr, timestamp, ne_name, object_id, metric_value
""")
```

Expected result:

| Load_date | Load_hr | timestamp | ne_name | object | metric_value | Min_UTIL | MAX_UTIL | AVG_UTIL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-08-10 | 15 | 2023-08-10T09:45 | AP1 | AP1.12.5 | {14311, 242342134, 13132} | 3.4 | 29.1 | 15.8 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix to this was to take out the cross join line completely and to add it to df1, changing the "unnest" function to the "explode" function. New code below executes in pyspark sql AWS Glue.

```
 df1 = spark.sql("""
 select *, EXPLODE(CAST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(metric_value, '[{}]',''), ',') AS ARRAY<VARCHAR(132)>)) AS raw_value
 FROM database.table
 WHERE date(load_date) = current_date - interval '1' day
""")

df1.createOrReplaceTempView("table1")

df2 = spark.sql("""  
SELECT load_date, load_hr, timestamp,
ne_name, object, metric_value, 
MIN(CAST((CASE WHEN trim(raw_value) = '' THEN NULL ELSE trim(raw_value) END) AS DOUBLE))/100 AS MIN_UTIL, 
MAX(CAST((CASE WHEN trim(raw_value) = '' THEN NULL ELSE trim(raw_value) END) AS DOUBLE))/100 AS 
MAX_UTIL, AVG(CAST((CASE WHEN trim(raw_value) = '' THEN NULL ELSE trim(raw_value)END) AS DOUBLE))/100 AS AVG_UTIL
FROM table1
WHERE metric_name = 'util'
group by load_date, load_hr, timestamp, ne_name, object_id, metric_value
""")
```